# Consume Liferay add user API with my new user

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I just consumed Liferay's /user/add-user json web service for creating user.
        Created user by using the URL

```
"http://localhost:9090/api/secure/jsonws/user/add-user/company-id/10153/auto-password/false/password1/123/password2/123/auto-screen-name/false/screen-name/raas/email-address/raas%40adfadf.com/male/true/send-email/true".
```

The default liferay admin "test" user authorization provided for the URL like ;

```
    String userPassword = "test" + ":" + "test"; 
    String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode (userPassword.getBytes());
    httpConn.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
```

And now, if I want to create a user with my second admin, how can I do authorization here?
        Is Liferay providing user tickets?
        Will that URL accept tickets? or please suggest any other ways.

Comment: Do you have to use the REST API for that? Can't you use the built-in local services instead?

Comment: That means, no way to do authorization with new admin?
Yes I would like to continue with REST APIs for now.